# handler never stops even if the application or the activity is not visible / being used

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, handler, runnable

I have the below handler

```
private Handler uiHandler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        switch (msg.what)
        {
        case UPDATE:
            // Perform UI updates here 

            // UI Updates done, schedule WORK in 15 seconds:
            this.sendMessageDelayed(this.obtainMessage(WORK), 15000);

            break;

        case WORK:
        {
            new Thread(checkUpdates).start();
        }
            break;

        default:
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
};
```

Inside `onResume()` I do the following :

`uiHandler.sendMessageDelayed(uiHandler.obtainMessage(WORK), 1000);`

Inside `onPause()` I do the following

`uiHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);`

BUT the handler never stops and keeps on repeating.

How to stop it ?

(Side questions : is using timer task with flags whether the UI is still around to do some updates a better option)

Comment: call Looper.dump after removeCallbacksAndMessages

Comment: @pskink how is that called ? can you be more specific ?

Comment: either call Looper.setMessageLogging once or Looper.dump whenever you want to see the Looper's MessageQueue